# Route 53 alias and S3 bucket not responding to changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I am using a route 53 alias that is connected to a S3 bucket with static website hosting enabled to redirect 1.0.0.0:8080 to example.mydomain.com.

This works the first time I create the bucket and alias. However if I want to change the details, it will continue to point to the original S3 bucket redirect request. For instance, if I want to change example.mydomain.com to point to port 8081, I would assume I could just change the S3 bucket redirect request details, but when I do this, it just sends me to port 8080. If I delete both the alias and the s3 bucket and create new ones that reflect the changes I want, example.mydomain.com will still send me to port 8080. If I create an alias and S3 bucket with a completely original subdomain (example2.mydomain.com pointing to 1.0.0.0:8081) then it will work.

It feels like something about the Route 53 alias or the redirect link needs to be refreshed, but I can't figure out what to change. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you are completely clearing your browser cache and restarting your browser between tests. Browsers love to cache redirect responses, and it can be difficult to clear those out of the cache without completely blowing away your browser cache.

Comment: Also, note that Route53 is just DNS, so it just points a domain to an IP. If you are only changing the port number then it is unrelated to DNS/Route53.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because your browser is caching the redirect more than anything.

If you take a look at the [amazon documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html), you can see it mentioning doing a 301 redirect. This means that the server is signalling that the location has ["Moved Permanently"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

Unfortunately, you can't use the mechanism you describe to do a temporary 302 redirect. You might want to look at using API Gateway and Lambda to achieve this.